# WebClient doesn't read response until request write is completed.

Tags: spring, webclient, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I'm trying to implement streaming proxy.
I faced with the issue with WebClient from spring reactive.

Could anyone help me to understand Do I some wrong way or it's just a bug from WebClient side?

**Stack:**

**reactor-netty 0.7.8.RELEASE**

**spring-boot 2.0.4.RELEASE**

**Desc:**

I want to proxy a long stream to external service and then forward stream of responses to the requester.
Streaming is happening using chunks (HTTP 1.1 Transfer-Encoding : chunked).
External service processes every chunk and sends to the response result.

**Expected behaviour:**

WebClient should read every received part of response immediately.

**Actual behaviour:**

WebClient doesn't start process response until request write is completed.

**Code:**

```
return client
    .post()
    .header("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")
//because I want to flush each received part
    .body((outputMessage, context) -> outputMessage.writeAndFlushWith(
        request.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers())
               .map(dataBuffer -> Mono.just(dataBuffer))))
    .exchange()
    .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
      ServerResponse.BodyBuilder bodyBuilder = ServerResponse.status(clientResponse.statusCode());
      bodyBuilder.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON);

      return bodyBuilder.body((outputMessage, context) ->                                                        
          outputMessage.writeAndFlushWith(                                               
            clientResponse.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers())                                                               
                          .map(dataBuffer -> Mono.just(dataBuffer))
                         ));}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked it up and it seems that by design, both Spring WebFlux's `WebClient` and Reactor Netty `HttpClient` are designed to first handle the request processing (sending the request body), and then reading the response body.

Other HTTP clients might allow this, but I think that in this case this is a way to link backpressure on both read/write operations and chain everything as a single reactive pipeline.

You might be looking for a message-oriented, bi-directionnal transport protocol with backpressure support. You can take a look at WebSockets (although you'll need to define your own message semantics there) or keep an eye on [RSocket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16751).

If you're just looking for an efficient reactive gateway, then [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/) is your best bet since it's reactive all the way down and supports interesting additional features.

A few additional notes:

Spring WebFlux (at both client and server levels) uses `Encoder` and `Decoder` implementations, adapting to the message Content-Type. Some specific content-types, such as `application/streaming+json` or `text/event-stream` are implemented with streaming scenarios in mind. This means that encoders are writing messages as they come, separated with specific characters, and flushing on the network. Using regular media types such as `application/octet-stream` or `application/json` will not trigger that behavior. For those cases, proxies and intermediaries might buffer the message body and deliver bigger/smaller windows. This is why such mechanisms require a separator between messages and proper codecs.

As far as I understand, you're using HTTP 1.1 which is using a request/response mechanism - the HTTP spec doesn’t explicitly forbid te server from writing the response before reading the full request, but it does say that it has to read the full request body (or close the connection) no matter what. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.4

As always, you can request enhancements on https://jira.spring.io, although in this case, I think this is done by design.

Comment: I’ talking about the HTTP content type header. If you’re not considering it or if it is « application/octet-stream » then the writeAndFlushWith are counter productive and regular writes are better

Comment: The content type is just bytes divided into chunks. I want to implement a similar process as at SSE but using transfer-encoding chunked. 

Http spec, If I understand correctly, doesn't have a strong restriction on reading the response before the request is completely written. 

Regarding perfomance degradation on flush, I gonna compare results with/without flushing every chunk.

Anyway the question was not about these. The question why  webclient is not listening to response stream?

Comment: Regarding flushing, How can I force flush when some amount of chunks is received? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Interesting. I’ll have to check that but by design WebClient might write everything before starting to read the response. One could argue that the server should not respond before receiving a full message body because it has to close the connection if it is invalid. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.4

Comment: You’re right this question is not about flushing, let’s cover that in a different question

Comment: Also: could you answer my question? What is the exact value of the http content-type header?

Comment: I don't specify this at the request and external service respond with application/json, but body contains many objects that coming by chunks. 1 chunk == 1 json object.

Comment: So you’re sending post requests without content type?

Comment: I've tried testing this use case with `application/streaming+json` and still got the behavior you described. I've updated my answer to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm marking as answered, but that particular behavior should be in the documentation. Also I can't use websocket or just simple tcp, as that external service not under my control. They break rules :)

Answer (score 2):

Just tested Jetty based WebClient implementation and it behaves as you expect. It can start reading response before all request content has been sent. 
It should have been released in Spring Framework 5.1
[WebClient on Jetty new feature issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15092)